# Write blob sequentially in varbinary column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sequential, varbinary

I have to restore some databases to a remote SQL Server. The problem is that they can be up to a few gb and this will cause an "OutOfMemory" exception when reading all bytes at one time. On smaller databases it is working without problems..

Now I try to stream the database sequentially to the SQL Server here:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + dbName + ".dbo.tempTable (blob) values (@data)";
    command.CommandTimeout = 900;

    SqlParameter dataParam = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    command.Parameters.Add(dataParam);

    SqlParameter offsetParam = new SqlParameter("@offset", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    command.Parameters.Add(offsetParam);

    SqlParameter lengthParam = new SqlParameter("@len", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    command.Parameters.Add(lengthParam);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read = 0;
        int offset = 0;

        while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dataParam.Value = buffer;
            offsetParam.Value = offset;
            lengthParam.Value = read;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (offset == 0)
            {
               command.CommandText = "UPDATE " + dbName + ".dbo.tempTable SET blob.WRITE(@data, @offset, @len)";
            }

            offset += read;
         }
     }
}
```

Now my problem:

A 500mb database takes more then 15 minutes and then it stops working with this exception:

> System.Data.Common.DbException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Thanks in advance,

Relax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself now. The problem was that i created a byte array with 8040 byte. This would be for a 520mb database about 50000 requests. I have changed the byte size to 8MB now.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8388608];
```

This works well now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the timeout is due to performance. My guess (not backed by any data, mind you) is that is blocking. Something prevents your query from executing. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for tips how to analyze performance problems such as yours, what to measure, what to look at and so on.

Note that your `UPDATE ... column.WRITE ...` is a prime candidate for [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), make sure you read on the [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

As a side note I have an article describing exactly your technique, including the reading of the BLOB: [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: btw I do not approve of the idea of streaming a DB into a BLOB column,  which is my understanding of what you're doing. Use a file transfer protocol.

Comment: you may have an example of this? There are some restrictions in my company but maybe there is a better way.